# The number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ that are solutions for the equation $\log_{2^a}\left(\log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)\right)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How many $(a,b)$ for $a,b \in \Bbb{N}$ pairs can satisfy the following equation:
$$\log_{2^a}\left(\log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)\right)=1$$
The answer is $3$, but I can't figure out how to get that answer.

---

*This is my attempt.*

$$\log_{2^a}\left(\log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)\right)=1$$
$$\frac{1}{a}\log_2\left(\log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)\right)=1$$
$$\log_2\left(\log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)\right)=a$$
$$\log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)=2^a$$
$$\frac{1}{b}\log_{2}\left(2^{1000}\right)=2^a$$
$$\log_{2}\left(2^{1000}\right)=2^ab$$
$$2^{1000}=2^{2^ab}$$
$$1000=2^ab$$
*That's it! This is dead end.*

*Honestly, this is the best I could do altough I very much doubt that I can get two variables by solving one equation (for that we need a system of equations!). So, I think that I need another approach that will either give me what $a$ and $b$ can be or direct answer (i.e. the number of possible values for $a$ and $b$), but I don't know which one.*

Comment: You probably meant $a,b\in\Bbb{N}$ otherwise we also have $a=-1,b=2000$,$a=-2,b=4000$ etc...

Comment: Hmmm... probably, but I'll check the original question.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: Depending on the definition of $\mathrm{N}$, we might also have $(a,b)=(0,1000)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your derivation

$$\log_{2^a}\left(\log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)\right)=1\iff \log_{2^b}\left(2^{1000}\right)=2^a\iff (2^b)^{2^a}=2^{1000}\iff b\cdot 2^a=1000$$

now we can have

- $a=1, 2^a=2, b=500$
- $a=2, 2^a=4, b=250$
- $a=3, 2^a=8, b=125$

Comment: How did you infer those values from $1000=b2^a$, i.e. how did you know that exactly those values are correct? What is the systematic way to get them?

Comment: I guess the question doesn't stipulate integers.

Comment: @Hanlon Indeed we can have only three solutions for a and b integers otherwise we woyld have infinitely many solutions. To find that we can start form a=1 and then proceed to find a=2 and a=3. From a=4 we can't have solutions since $b$ is no more integer.